# AngularJS 1.6 with jQuery Steps (plugin) asynchronous content loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, asynchronous

I'm having a problem that after loading HTML content dynamically asynchronously with the [jQuery Steps](http://www.jquery-steps.com/Examples#async) plugin:

```
<section data-mode="async" data-url="test.html"></section>
```

The `AngularJS` does not detect the content and thus all elements that contain the `ng-show` directives are displayed instead of being hidden as expected.

<del>Punkler with the problem</del> - **Edit - Solved (Punkler updated)**:

http://plnkr.co/edit/6p1dVln2R9Pgb9ivoMcX?p=preview

P.S.: I need the load to be asynchronous because the amount of HTML data I have to load is excessive.

Comment: Either use Angular, or jQuery. Get rid of jQuery entirely, that's the solution.

Comment: You don't have to get rid of your jQuery but you have to use angular for the async loading because you need to make sure angular is run after the template is loaded. Here is a post that suggests one solution where you use directives to asynchronously load templates. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21196245/load-angular-directive-template-async

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `ng-include` for dynamic template load in `angularjs`

```
<section ng-include="'test.html'"></section>
```

and i've removed `ng-show` from `test.html` to make it visible

See working [**Plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/pZ1g2XXNkQ8RT5pl5Upg?p=preview)

Comment: HTML data that I have to load is excessive. How to use the next button of the Wizard then to load on demand? What do I have to put inside the controller?

Answer (score 0):

**Solved - (Punkler Updated)**

http://plnkr.co/edit/6p1dVln2R9Pgb9ivoMcX?p=preview

I use `ng-include` with `onload`:

```
<!-- Jquery Steps HTML Template -->
<div id="wizard" ng-controller="wizardCtrl">
  <h3><i class="fa fa-question-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i> Arroz</h3>
  <section>
    <div ng-if="index == '1'" ng-include="'test.html'" onload="finishLoading()"></div>
  </section>
</div>

<script>
  // Jquery Steps Plugin
  $wizard = $("#wizard");
  $wizard.steps({
    headerTag: "h3",
    bodyTag: "section",

    enableFinishButton: false,
    enablePagination: true,
    enableAllSteps: false,
    forceMoveForward: true,
    titleTemplate: "#title#",
    cssClass: "wizard tabcontrol",

    labels: {
      loading: ""
    }
  });

  angular.module('myApp', [])
    .controller('wizardCtrl', ['$scope', '$timeout', function($scope, $timeout){
        $scope.index = "1";

        $scope.finishLoading = function (){
            // jQuery Steps
            var index = $wizard.steps("getCurrentIndex");
            // ...

            return true;
        };
    }]);
</script>
```

With `ng-if`, you can load the content of the tabs on-demand, that is, you can use the jQuery Steps method called `getCurrentIndex` to get the current steps index. <[Steps Methods](https://github.com/rstaib/jquery-steps/wiki/Methods)>

Using `autoload`overrides the `onContentLoaded` method of Async Content load. <[Steps Events](https://github.com/rstaib/jquery-steps/wiki/Settings)>